# Overriding the package.loaded table in a function in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to override the `package.loaded` table in the scope of a function using `setfenv`, but it's not quite working.

```lua
local env = {
  require = require,
  print = print,
  package = {
    cpath = package.cpath,
    loadlib = package.loadlib,
    path = package.path,
    preload = package.preload,
    seeall = package.seeall,
    loaded = {
      foobar = {
        fn = function() print("hello world") end,
      },
    },
  },
}
setfenv(assert(loadstring("require('foobar')")), env)()
```

Executing the above code, will result in a error because the module `foobar` isn't found.
It seems that it's for some reason not picking up the `package` table override that I've specified in the environment.
How do I make this work?

Comment: `require` doesn't index `getfenv(1).package.loaded`; it indexes `_G.package.loaded` no matter the current environment. You could write a custom `require` function for your environment that just returns the `foobar` module.

Comment: @Kyle - `require` in Lua does not work with environments, it read the `loaded` table in the main environment and it always loads a module in the main environment.  You need to reimplement `require` to make it respect environments.

Comment: I see, I went with modifying the `require` in the environment instead and it works pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleRichards, perhaps you could add your solution as an answer for the benefit of others.